# longitude and latitude coordinates

Tags: google-maps, gps, latitude-longitude

Is there any way to get all the Longitude and Latitude coordinates for a single area/location ?

For example, There are many Longitude and Latitude coordinates within Central Park NY. But Google map only points with a single coordinate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objects in a digital map are represented as poly lines or closed polygons.
more complex objects like the central park, can also have wholes inside (the lakes).
This is called a multi polygon: outer boundary with inner wholes.
Each point (vertex) of that polygon has a coordinate expressed in latitude, longitude.
You would need the vector data of all central park multi polygons.
The vector data you cannot get from google. you could get them from OpenStreetMap, but probably not via a standard service.